# $x^4+x^2=\frac{11}{5}$ then what is the value of $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

> $x^4+x^2=\frac{11}{5}$ then what is the value of $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$ ?

My approaches which didn't yield anything

I tried manipulating $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$ 
Observations

- $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\frac{(x+1)(x^3-x^2+2x-2)}{(x-1)(x^3-x^2+2x-2)}=\frac{x^4+x^2-2}{x^4-2x^3+3x^2-4x+2}=\frac{\frac{11}{5}-2}{\frac{11}{5}-2x^3+2x^2-4x+2}$ which is not giving any assistance to find the required value.
- let a=$\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$
  then we observe that
  $a^3=2\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}+3a$ which again is not useful

how should we proceed then to get the required ?

Comment: *Hint :* use Componendo-Dividendo

Comment: If we set $u=x^2$ in the equation, $x^4+x^2=\frac{11}{5}$. We get a quadratic equation to solve which gives us that $u=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{\frac{59}{5}}}{2}$. So by substituting this value of $x$ via $u$ and after some simplification we may get the value of required expression.

Comment: By brute force, the value of $a$ is a root of [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%285x%5E4%2B5x%5E2-11%2C+%28a%5E3+-+3a%29+%28x%5E2-1%29+-+2%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2C+x%29+%3D+0) polynomial of $12^{th}$ degree, which factors into squares of a quartic and a quadratic. Without using a CAS, the polynomial can be derived by taking $\,x^2 = \frac{a^3-3a+2}{a^3-3a-2}\,$ from the last relation and substituting back into the original equation, but the calculations are laborious.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = ...$ "which again is not useful", wrong here, it is.

Let $a = x^2$

$a^2 + a - \frac{11}{5} = 0$

$a = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4 * 1 * \frac{-11}{5}}}{2}$

$a = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{\frac{49}{5}}}{2}$

$a = \frac{-1 \pm \frac{7\sqrt{5}}{5}}{2}$

$a = \frac{-5\pm {7\sqrt{5}}}{10}$

$x^2 = \frac{-5\pm {7\sqrt{5}}}{10}$

$x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-5+{7\sqrt{5}}}{10}}$

Let $y$ = $^3\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}+$ $^3\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$

From your observation, $y^3 = \frac{2x^2+2}{x^2-1} + 3y$

Sub the value found for $x$:

$y^3 - 3y - 14\sqrt{5}-32 = 0$

Use the cubic formula without the $bx^2$ term in there. See origins of cubic formula for more info.

Without the $b$ constant we get a simplified version of the formula.

$y =$ $^3\sqrt{\frac{-d}{2a} + \sqrt{(\frac{-d}{2a})^2 + (\frac{c}{3a})^3}} +$ $^3\sqrt{\frac{-d}{2a} - \sqrt{(\frac{-d}{2a})^2 + (\frac{c}{3a})^3}}$

Note how this resembles the original part of the question we were finding for.

Another way to solve it:

Let $f(y) = y^3 - 3y - 14\sqrt{5}-32$

Cubics at most have $3$ real roots (atleast $1$ real, and the other $2$ complex).

In their factored form, $(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)$, $a*b*c = d$ in $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Therefore, our roots must multiply to $-14\sqrt{5}-32$, or $abc = -14\sqrt{5}-32$. But before that we must define how many roots (1, 2 or 3) are there.

Taking $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$, there is a maximum at $(-1, 61.305)$ and minimum at $(1, 65.305)$. Notice how the curves are way below the horizontal axis, so the $f(y)$ has only **1** root, for $y > 0$.

This means the $f(y)$ can be factored into a form resembling $(y + a)(y^2 + cy + d)$, where is $-a$ is the root and $(y^2 + cy + d)$ is irreducible.

So, $ay^2 + cy^2 = 0$, as there is no squared term. Therefore, $c = -a$.

$ad  = -14\sqrt{5}-32$

$acy + dy = -3y$

If you simultaneously solve, you will get $a = - 2 - \sqrt{5}$. Therefore, $(y - 2 - \sqrt{5}) = 0$ and your root is $2 + \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Looks right now (+1), but "*can't be done algebraically*" $-$ it actually can, your value is in fact $\,2+\sqrt{5}\,$.

Comment: Indeed it can, i was finding a solution after the last edit and I did (it took a while)

Comment: @dxiv how can it be done algebraically ? I'm able to solve the last equation $y^3-3y-14\sqrt5 -32=0$

Comment: Let $a =  \sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$. Then you need to find $a + 1/a = k$ and raise both sides to the power of $3$: oops, this is the same as before.

Comment: @Chayan Either using the cubic formula and denesting the radicals, or by "guessing" a solution in the form $u+v\sqrt{5} \,\mid\, u,v \in \mathbb Q$ and solving for rational $u,v$.